# Trap the mouse!

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest program possible that traps the mouse cursor inside an upward pointing equilateral triangle with a side length of 274 pixels and a centroid at the exact middle of the screen.
(Triangle because of cheese wedges.)

While your program is running, the tip of the cursor should never be able to move outside of this triangle, and should move and function normally inside. When the `Esc` key is hit the program must end, releasing the mouse.

## Scoring

This is code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins. You may only use standard ASCII.

## Details

- Besides things like shutting off the computer or killing the process or pressing `Alt-F4` or `Ctrl-Alt-Delete`, the only way to release the cursor should be the `Esc` key.
- If the cursor is outside the triangle when the program starts it should be placed somewhere inside.
- The cursor must be able to move smoothly up and down the two angled sides of the triangles.
- If the display is extended over multiple monitors the triangle may appear in the center of any one monitor or the center of all of them combined. (If you only have one monitor you do not need to test for this.)
- It's fine if touchscreen users can still click things outside the triangle.

*Tiny bonus question:* Where did I get 274 from?

Comment: Tiny bonus answer: the side length was chosen to fit triangle area into 2^15 pixels?

Comment: Tini bonus answer: Perhaps because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_triangular_number / oeis.org/A005448 ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff and flawr Nope.

Comment: How are you measuring the 274 pixels along the angled sides of the triangle? Since each pixel is a square, counting 274 pixels will result in an isosceles triangle whose top sides are longer than the base by a factor of sqrt(2)

Comment: @Timmy The triangle peak should measure 274 pixels in Euclidean distance from the two endpoints of the base. It's fine if rounding error makes this imperfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## AutoHotKey (249)

```
CoordMode,Mouse
Esc::ExitApp
U(a,b){
return(a+b+abs(a-b))/2
}
L(a,b){
return(a+b-abs(a-b))/2
}
t::
SysGet,X,0
Sysget,Y,1
M:=X/2
N:=Y/2
Loop{
MouseGetPos,x,y
MouseMove L(U(M-137,x),M+137),L(U(N-118+1.732*abs(x-M),y),N+119),0
}
return
```

It doesn't have inbuilt min/max functions, so I spent 72 chars reimplementing them.

Press `t` to trap the cursor, I dont know if its possible to do stuff without assigning it to a hotkey.

The movement is not very smooth, unless you move the mouse slowly

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Python <s>418</s> <s>351</s> <s>314</s> <s>300</s> 263 Bytes

Edit: Saved <s>67</s> <s>104</s> <s>118</s> 155 Bytes thanks to the advice in the comments

```
from win32api import*
from msvcrt import*
s=137
G=GetSystemMetrics
S=SetCursorPos
x=G(0)//2
y=G(1)//2
c=3**.5
Y=y-2*s/c
S((x,y))
while(kbhit()and ord(getch())==27)<1:a,b=GetCursorPos();S((min(max(a,x-s),x+s),min(max(b,int(c*a+Y-c*x),int(-c*a+Y+c*x)),int(y+s/c))))
```

Written in Python 3.4.1 on Windows, pywin needs to be installed.

My first code golf submission. Please feel free to suggest improvements

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can do `from ... import*` which saves 3 bytes in your code

Comment: You can write `274/2` as `137` to save 2 characters. Assigning the common subexpression `y-2*S/c` to a one-letter var and referencing it in `d` and `e` should save some more. The `if b<X:b=int(X)` pattern can probably be written like `b=max(b,int(X))` (and `>` rewritten with min, respectively). Finally, there's probably some more whitespace to squeeze out, e.g. between `kbhit()` and `and`.

Comment: since you are using some functions more then once you should assign them to a shorter name `G=GetSystemMetrics;x=G(0)/2;y=G(1)/2`(since the resolutions is always an integer and multiple of 2 you can save 2 slashes), same for SetCursorPos. And if you use c=3**.5 then you dont need to import math

Comment: @DenDenDo I wasn't aware of the functions shortcut. Thank you. The single slash division did not work since ``540.0`` still counts as a float

Comment: You can save another 3bytes by using `map`: `b=min(max(b,*map(int,[c*a+d,-c*a+e,y+s/c])))`. You also don't need the parens around `a` and `b`: `a,b=GetCursorPos()` which saves 2bytes. You ALSO don't need to recalculate and store `a` and `b`. Simply put the calculations into the call to `S`: `S((min(max(a,x-s),x+s),min(max(b,int(c*a+d),int(-c*a+e)),int(y+s/c))))` which saves 4bytes.

Comment: @BeetDemGuise ``map`` wouldn't work because the three values are compared over two stages ``b,int(c*a+d),int(-c*a+e)`` first, then the result with ``int(y+s/c)``. All the other suggestions worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: If you don't need the short circuit behaviour of `and`, you can replace `kbhit()and ord(getch())==27` with `kbhit()*ord(getch())==27` to save 3 characters, because True is cast to 1 and False is cast to 0 in Python. Also, you can put the first and second lines of the while loop on the same line, separated by a semicolon, to save another character. Finally, you only use `d` and `e` once each, so there is no point in defining them as variable. Just put `Y-c*x` and `Y+c*x` in the proper locations.

Comment: @isaacg saved another 12 bytes, thank you. ``kbhit()*ord(getch())==27`` did not work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I see the problem - you can't call getch until kbhit has occured, so the short cicruit behavior is needed. However, you could probably put that in the while condition (`while 1>(kbhit()and ord(getchr())==27`) instead of using a separate `if` and `break`.

Comment: @isaacg That worked out better. Brilliant!

Comment: Another idea: Make it `while(...)<1:` to remove a space.